# vb.net Loop through public structure and pass to generics

Tags: vb.net, generics

I have inherited some god awful vb.net code and having trouble trying to work out the generics for looping through the current structure in place.

here is a snippet of the struct

```
    Public Structure ApplicationDetails
    Dim ID As Integer
    Dim AgentID As Integer
    Dim ApplicationDate As Date
    Dim CompletedDate As Date
```

here is the madness to populate it

```
With ApplicationInfo
            .ID = If(Not IsDBNull(DT(0)("ID")), DT(0)("ID"), Nothing)
            .ApplicationDate = If(Not IsDBNull(DT(0)("ApplicationDate")), DT(0)("MortgageAmount"), Nothing)
            .CompletedDate = If(Not IsDBNull(DT(0)("CompleteDate")), DT(0)("MortgageAmount"), Nothing)
```

now i want to do something like this:

```
       For Each item In ApplicationInfo.GetType().GetProperties()
            Dim thisType = item.GetType()
            Dim name = item.Name
            Dim value = DtItem(Of item.GetType())(0, name.ToString(), DT)
            item.SetValue(item, value, Nothing)
        Next
Private Function DtItem(Of T)(ByVal num As Integer, ByVal name As String, ByRef DT As DataTable) As T
    Return If(Not IsDBNull(DT(num)(name)), DT(num)(name), Nothing)
End Function
```

but i am not sure on the syntax to set the value and when trying to get the type i get item.GetTYpe() is not declared.    I know i must be on the right track, just missing a little something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number of issues.

First and foremost, `SetValue` only works on object types, not values, so you would have to change your Structure to a Class.

```
Public Class ApplicationDetails
End Class
```

Next, you are looping through properties but your "structure" only had fields.  So you need to add properties:

```
Public Class ApplicationDetails
  Private _ID As Integer

  Property ID As Integer
    Get
      Return _ID
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
      _ID = value
    End Set
  End Property

  //' etc

End Class
```

Otherwise, you would have to work with `GetFields`.

I don't think Generics will work here since you are only dealing with objects and you don't know the type (despite reflection):

```
Private Function DtItem(ByVal num As Integer, ByVal name As String, ByRef DT As DataTable) As Object
  Return If(Not IsDBNull(DT(num)(name)), DT(num)(name), Nothing)
End Function
```

Lastly, your reflection call is wrong.  Try changing it to this:

```
For Each item As PropertyInfo In ApplicationInfo.GetType().GetProperties
  Dim value As Object = DtItem(0, item.Name, _dt)
  If item.CanWrite Then
    item.SetValue(ApplicationInfo, value, Nothing)
  End If
Next
```

I'm not sure doing this through reflection is gaining you anything.  In your "madness" example, it looks like you might be trying to put in a `MortgageAmount`, which I assume is a decimal, into a date field.  That might be needed to look at.

Comment: right okay  and ignore the values etc, i just copied a block out, havent done .net forms for many years and VB never and that little section goes on to do over 100 items, hence the reason for me trying to find a cheat way around it.   the whole project is going to be rebuilt so think i will leave it out for now, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rethink your functional decomposition there. You're not getting much out of moving one line into a function, and I don't think you'll be able to pass a type constructor to a generic the way you are attempting to do so. You're also confusing some of your type checks.

Try something along these lines instead:

```
For Each item In ApplicationInfo.GetType().GetProperties()
    Dim theName As String = item.Name,
        isNullable = Not item.PropertyType.IsValueType OrElse _
                     Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(item.PropertyType) IsNot Nothing

    If item.CanWrite Then
        If Not IsDBNull(DT(0)(theName))
            item.SetValue(ApplicationInfo, DT(0)(theName), Nothing)
        ElseIf isNullable
            item.SetValue(ApplicationInfo, Nothing, Nothing)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

If your code is executed immediately after the object is initialized, the `isNullable` checks are extraneous and you could simply take no action as the properties will be initialized as null. Otherwise, I'd recommend performing the check so you don't attempt to assign `Nothing` to a value type, which is going to throw an exception. Alternatively, you could modify your structure to use nullable reference types, i.e.:

```
Public Structure ApplicationDetails
    Property ID As Integer?
    Property AgentID As Integer?
    Property ApplicationDate As Date?
    Property CompletedDate As Date?
End Structure
```

**EDIT**

As LarsTech points out, your structure members are not properties and this will not function as anticipated unless you modify your structure to indicate these fields are in fact properties, for which the compiler would automatically generate getters and setters.